# clojure.algo.monad strange m-plus behaviour with parser-m - why is second m-plus evaluated?

Tags: clojure, monads, state-monad

I'm getting unexpected behaviour in some monads I'm writing.
I've created a parser-m monad with

```
(def parser-m (state-t maybe-m))
```

which is pretty much the example given everywhere ([here](http://www.intensivesystems.net/tutorials/monads_101.html), [here](http://brehaut.net/blog/2010/ghosts_in_the_machine) and [here](http://www.rierol.net/clojure-monads.html))

I'm using m-plus to act as a kind of fall-through query mechanism, in my case, it first reads values from a cache (database), if that returns nil, the next method is to read from "live" (a REST call).

However, the second value in the m-plus list is always called, even though its value is disgarded (if the cache hit was good) and the final return is that of the first monadic function.

Here's a cutdown version of the issue i'm seeing, and some solutions I found, but I don't know why.

My questions are:

1. Is this expected behaviour or a bug in m-plus? i.e. will the 2nd method in a m-plus list always be evaluated even if the first item returns a value?
2. Minor in comparison to the above, but if i remove the call
   `_ (fetch-state)` from checker, when i evaluate that method, it
   prints out the messages for the functions the m-plus is calling
   (when i don't think it should). Is this also a bug?

Here's a cut-down version of the code in question highlighting the problem. It simply checks key/value pairs passed in are same as the initial state values, and updates the state to mark what it actually ran.

```
(ns monads.monad-test
  (:require [clojure.algo.monads :refer :all]))

(def parser-m (state-t maybe-m))

(defn check-k-v [k v]
  (println "calling with k,v:" k v)
  (domonad parser-m
           [kv (fetch-val k)
            _ (do (println "k v kv (= kv v)" k v kv (= kv v)) (m-result 0))
            :when (= kv v)
            _ (do (println "passed") (m-result 0))
            _ (update-val :ran #(conj % (str "[" k " = " v "]")))
            ]
           [k v]))

(defn filler []
  (println "filler called")
  (domonad parser-m
           [_ (fetch-state)
            _ (do (println "filling") (m-result 0))
            :when nil]
           nil))

(def checker
  (domonad parser-m
           [_ (fetch-state)
            result (m-plus
                    ;; (filler) ;; intitially commented out deliberately
                    (check-k-v :a 1)
                    (check-k-v :b 2)
                    (check-k-v :c 3))]
           result))

(checker {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :ran []})
```

When I run this as is, the output is:

```
> (checker {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :ran []})
calling with k,v: :a 1
calling with k,v: :b 2
calling with k,v: :c 3
k v kv (= kv v) :a 1 1 true
passed
k v kv (= kv v) :b 2 2 true
passed
[[:a 1] {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :ran ["[:a = 1]"]}]
```

I don't expect the line `k v kv (= kv v) :b 2 2 true` to show at all. The final result is the value returned from the first function to m-plus, as I expect, but I don't expect the second function to even be called.

Now, I've found if I pass a filler into m-plus that does nothing (i.e. uncomment the `(filler)` line) then the output is correct, the :b value isn't evaluated.

If I don't have the filler method, and make the first method test fail (i.e. change it to `(check-k-v :a 2)` then again everything is good, I don't get a call to check :c, only a and b are tested.

From my understanding of what the `state-t maybe-m` transformation is giving me, then the m-plus function should look like:

```
(defn m-plus
  [left right]
  (fn [state]
    (if-let [result (left state)]
      result
      (right state))))
```

which would mean that `right` isn't called unless `left` returns nil/false.

**Edit:**
After looking at state-t and maybe-m source, the m-plus looks more like:

```
(fn [& statements]
  (fn [state]
    (apply (fn [& xs]
             (first (drop-while nil? xs)))
           (map #(% state) statements))))
```

But the principle is the same, `(first (drop-while nil? ...)` should only execute over the items that return a valid value.

I'd be interested to know if my understanding is correct or not, and why I have to put the filler method in to stop the extra evaluation (whose effects I don't want to happen).

**Edit:**

If I switch over to using [Jim Duey's hand written implementation of parser-m](http://www.intensivesystems.net/tutorials/monads_101.html) (from his excellent blogs), there is no evaluation of the second function in m-plus, which seems to imply the transformation monad is breaking m-plus. However, even in this implementation, if I remove the initial `(fetch-state)` call in the `checker` function, the domonad definition causes the output of the creation of the m-plus functions, suggesting something going on in domonad's implementation I'm not expecting.

Apologies for the long winded post!

Comment: I'm suspecting after a recent SO thread I read that the problem is apply reading a number of args in order to determine the arity of the function, causing it to invoke an extra method.